# Multiple statements in case MDX

Tags: sql-server, mdx, business-intelligence, olap

I have to write MDX that will be displayed on column and is dividing rows into three groups. First group is distinguished by few numbers, second one is by attribute, and third group is where rest doesn't fit.

My code looks like that so far:

```
case 
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "4254255527"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "2752637520"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "5637839739"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "9378793737"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "3789789397"  then "ABC"
    when [Document].[Document series].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "XYZ" then "XYZ"
    else "Rest"
end
```

But I'm getting "Rest" everytime.

How should I correct that?

Edit:
Another try but still not working:

```
case 
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].[&5196189651]  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].[&7885181585]  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].[&7511535861]  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].[&4742575277]  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].[&7272727272]  then "ABC"
    when [Customer's Document].[Document Series].[&CHP] then "XYZ"
    else "Rest"
end
```

Comment: What is the value, key and name properties for Customer's Document ?. What is the structure for Customer dimension ?. How do you query this measure and see the 'Rest' as your end results? add the query to your question please so that we can help.

Comment: @Dodzik - is the Dimension `[Customer]` on the rows of the eventual SELECT clause?! if it isn't on rows then Currentmember is the All member ....currentmember only functions if the dimension is actually _current_ i.e in context. This is probably the reason you get Rest all the time. Can you add the remainder of your mdx script please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling you want to do something more like the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [ABC] AS 
    {
      [Customer].[Customer's Document].&[5196189651]
     ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].&[7885181585]
     ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].&[7511535861]
     ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].&[4742575277]
     ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].&[7272727272]
    } 
  MEMBER [Customer].[All].[ABC] AS 
    Aggregate([ABC]) 
  MEMBER [Customer].[All].[XYZ] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer's Document].[Document Series].&[CHP] 
  SET [REST] AS 
    Except
    (
      [Customer].[Customer's Document].MEMBERS
     ,[ABC]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Customer].[All].[Rest] AS 
    Aggregate([REST]) 
  SET [FINAL] AS 
    {
      [Customer].[All].[ABC]
     ,[Customer].[All].[XYZ]
     ,[Customer].[All].[Rest]
    } 
SELECT 
  [FINAL] ON 1
 ,{[Measures].[Amount]} ON 0
FROM [YourCube];
```

Or maybe the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [ABC] AS 
    {
      [Customer].[Customer's Document].&[5196189651]
     ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].&[7885181585]
     ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].&[7511535861]
     ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].&[4742575277]
     ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].&[7272727272]
    } 
  MEMBER [Customer].[All].[ABC] AS 
    Aggregate([ABC]) 
  MEMBER [Customer].[All].[XYZ] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer's Document].[Document Series].&[CHP] 
  SET [REST] AS 
    Except
    (
      [Customer].[Customer's Document].MEMBERS
     ,{
        [ABC]
       ,[Customer].[Customer's Document].[Document Series].&[CHP]
      }
    ) 
  MEMBER [Customer].[All].[Rest] AS 
    Aggregate([REST]) 
  SET [FINAL] AS 
    {
      [Customer].[All].[ABC]
     ,[Customer].[All].[XYZ]
     ,[Customer].[All].[Rest]
    } 
SELECT 
  [FINAL] ON 1
 ,{[Measures].[Amount]} ON 0
FROM [YourCube];
```

---

**Edit**

Just a warning - in the accepted answer there is the following `mdx`:

```
case 
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "4254255527"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "2752637520"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "5637839739"  then "ABC"
...
...
```

This might be marked as the solution but it's not great `mdx`. In this circumstance the `IS` operator should be used:

```
case 
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER IS 
             [Customer].[Customer's Document].[Customer's Document].&[4254255527]  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER IS 
             [Customer].[Customer's Document].[Customer's Document].&[2752637520]  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER IS 
             [Customer].[Customer's Document].[Customer's Document].&[5637839739]  then "ABC"
...
...
```

Comment: Did you mean to have the '&' outside of brackets [Customer].[Customer's Document].&[7272727272]

Comment: @Ala I just copied the member names from the original question, but yes you are correct the `&` would usually be outside the braces.

Comment: @Dodzik - I had a feeling that this was marked incorrectly as the general mdx in Proffesore's answer is not great - doing this `t].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "4254255527"` is a poor alternative to using the `IS` operator

Answer (score 0):

Which BI tool are you using; You can add this to a new column as a name calculation to the data source view(right click on Customer table->New Named Calculation->ColumnName:XXX). 
Example :

```
CASE 
    WHEN ACOLUMN BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 'ABC'
    WHEN ACOLUMN BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN 'ABC'
    ELSE 'REST'
END
```

I believe that in the CASE you have to use the same hierarchy.Alternative you can Break your code to 2 parts:

```
case 
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "4254255527"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "2752637520"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "5637839739"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "9378793737"  then "ABC"
    when [Customer].[Customer's Document].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "3789789397"  then "ABC"
    when [Document].[Document series].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "XYZ" then "XYZ"
    else "Rest"
end

CASE
when [Document].[Document series].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "XYZ" then "XYZ"
    else "Rest"
end
```